# Multiple button call the same function (and function knows which button made call)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have this button code which is similar in two buttons (part of the code)

```
btn.frame=CGRectMake(600,400,30,30);]
btn.addTarget:self actionL@selector(authButtonAction)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

and in the function (dummy code)

```
-(void)authButtonAction {
    if btn1 was clicked btn1.caption=y else btn1.caption=2
}
```

My button works and my function is called but what I was trying to do is to somehow find out which button was clicked...pass that to `authButtonAction`. Because that would save me from writing X amount of functions and I could use an if statement in one function.

Comment: try to set some tag to the button & check the tag & apply conditions accordingly.

Comment: @Girish: that is perfect answer, why you shy to give it as answer?

Comment: @Anoop: if the problem is solved using single line of comment then there is no need of answer.

Comment: @Girish:Try to earn more points and you will get more privileges... But at the end of the day, you have to learn, not points only matters :)

Comment: @Anoop: Only earning point is not the matter, learn & earn is my aim, so I am doing this. But anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Set a tag to your button..

```
#define TAG_BUTTON_ONE 1
#define TAG_BUTTON_TWO 2

oneButton       =  [[UIButton alloc] ......];
oneButton.tag   =  TAG_BUTTON_ONE;
[oneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
-----
-----

twoButton       = [[UIButton alloc] ....];
twoButton.tag   = TAG_BUTTON_TWO;
[twoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
---
--
```

In button handler, check for sender's tag

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender{
   if(sender.tag == TAG_BUTTON_ONE){
      //handle button one click
   }else if(sender.tag == TAG_BUTTON_TWO){
      //handle button 2 click
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `btn.Tag` to an id for your button, then use that to determine which button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your button method should have a colon on the end of its name. The button will pass itself as the sender argument. You can query that to find out which button was clicked (based on its title or tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can give tags to button and then can check tag of tappedButton in action method.

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
int buttonTag = pressedButton.tag;
if (buttonTag==1)
{
NSLog(@"Button 1 Pressed");
}
else
{
NSLog (@"Button 2 Pressed");
}
}
```